# Reducing Data Points in a graph

Tags: data-visualization

What is the best algorithm to reduce the number of data points in a scatterplot? I have a fairly evenly distributed data and want to reduce the number of data points by dividing the graph in sectors and pick just a single representative point in a sector instead of the hundreds or thousands.

I have come across sampling and binning but not sure which is the right approach to take.

Edit: I have added the scatter plot example [image: ScatterPlot]

Comment: It sounds as if you would like to cluster your data and plot the cluster centers instead of all data points. Could you upload your current scatterplot and add it to your question?

Comment: Thanks @NikolasRieble I have added the scatter plot to the example. Is there a good algorithm to space the clusters into even grids and then plot the closest data point to the centroid if possible.

Comment: If you wish to plot in a more understandable way, you might want to chose a heatmap instead of a scatterplot. Clustering seems to be not the way to go here. Further: A different color scale could also help instead of dark blue to light blue, try green to red or other colors which are more distinguishable

Comment: @NikolasRieble I have different plots based on this data. But the preprocessing takes a long time. So I need to reduce the raw data itself picking just one point in a sector which is closest to the center of the sector. Are there any other means to achieve this?  Thanks

Comment: Split the n*m image into equally sized patches of size a*b whereas n/m = a/b. Then plot either mean(patch) or max(patch) for each patch.

Comment: It's doubtful that a scatterplot will be helpful for understanding these data.  You seem to have a regular gridded sample of a 2D function, as indicated by the variation of colors of the points.  One would think you might wish to *interpolate* them into a regular surface, visualize that surface, and analyze it further.  What is it you really want to accomplish with these data?

Comment: @whuber I plot contour plots using this data. There are multiple variables which have better resolution. However the plotting library (gnuplot) struggles with the amount of data so I am looking for a way to reduce the number of data points on the graph by dividing it into sectors and then just pick one point per sector.

Comment: This is so little data (you can't have more than a few thousand points) that I suspect you are not selecting the most appropriate method to create the contour plots: a simple spline, IDW, or nearest neighbor interpolator will take no perceptible time and require little RAM.  Regardless, it's important to supply this extra information (which currently appears sprinkled among the comments) within the post itself, for otherwise you are likely to get answers, which although they might be mathematically correct, will perform poorly for your situation.